# split array contents into another array php

Tags: php, arrays, project, extract, explode

hi there im pretty new at php ... just working on a homework and we have this task to separate an array that has contents.. but the trick is to separate the contents and put it in a new array with the contents organized.

However, my new array is wrong. One index should contain all names into 1 string
another index with all the phone numbers ...etc

mine displays like the one at picture

Any suggestions? the pic of code is also attached

[image: so this is the new array]

[image: this is the code]

```
<pre>
<?php
$fileName = "c:/wamp/www/datebook";

$line = file($fileName);

print_r($line);

foreach($line as $value)
{
    $newLine[] = explode(":",$value);

}

print_r($newLine);
?>
</pre>
```

these is little piece, they are 26 in total.. thats from notepad

```
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100
Sir Lancelot:837-835-8257:474 Camelot Boulevard, Bath, WY 28356:5/13/69:24500
Jesse Neal:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
```

Comment: okay done, so thats a txt file... each line is like that... with (:) as delim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $fileName = "c:/wamp/www/datebook";

    $line = file($fileName);

    $newLine= array();
    foreach($line as $va)
    {   
        $new = explode(":",$va);
        $newLine['name'][] = $new[0];
        $newLine['phone'][] = $new[1];
        $newLine['etc'][] = $new[2];
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newLine);
    ?>
```

This will Output

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jon DeLoach
            [1] => Joo Del
        )

    [phone] => Array
        (
            [0] => 408-253-3122
            [1] => 408-253-3122
        )

    [etc] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7/25/53
            [1] => 7/25/53
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
// The indexes to be set to new array [Currently I am assuming, You can change accordingly]
$indexes= array(
    'Name' , 'Phone', 'Address', 'Date', 'Value'
);

$new = array();
// Loop through the indexes array
foreach($indexes as $key => $index) {
    // extract column data & implode them with [,]
    $new[$index] = implode(', ', array_column($newline, $key));
}
```

**array_column** is supported **PHP >= 5.5**

[Example](https://eval.in/529171)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them to their own arrays.

```
$line = explode("\n", $s);

$newLine = array('name' => '','phone' => ''); // add the rest of the columns.....address,etc
foreach($line as $value)
{
    list($name,$phone,$address,$date,$postcode) = explode(":",$value);

    $newLine['name'] .= (empty($newLine['name'])? $name : " ". $name);
    $newLine['phone'] .= (empty($newLine['phone'])? $phone : " ". $phone);
    // etc
}
```

And that'll add them appropriately.

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#RASDVqszg) (*just press `ctrl` + `enter` to run it*)

And it returns an associative array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jon DeLoach
            [phone] => 408-253-3122
            [address] => 123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sir Lancelot
            [phone] => 837-835-8257
            [address] => 474 Camelot Boulevard, Bath, WY 28356
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jesse Neal
            [phone] => 408-233-8971
            [address] => 45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303
        )

)
```

Comment: But my goal is to have a single array, with each index containing particular data... [names] => ........... contains all names as 1 string with spaces as delim then [phone] => .........all phones separated with spaces

Comment: @javaMan1995 ahhhhhhhh right. I'll update this answer shortly